# How to get the count from a specific column and display separately

Tags: sql

I would like to check how can I re-write the query so I can show the different stages in different columns

original query:

```
select order_id, stage from table
```

original result:

```
order_id  stage
111       1
111       1
222       1
111       2
111       3
111       4
222       2
```

the result i would like to see is based on the count of each stage:

```
order_id  stage_1 stage_2 stage_3 stage_4
111       2       1       1       1
222       1       1
```

sorry for the trouble and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(column_name)
FROM table_name;
```

This will return the number of rows from one column.

For more Details:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp

Comment: Hi Sir, I would like to display the different stages (stage_1, stage_2, stage_3, stage_4) in separate columns while displaying the count, is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out already, thanks for the replies

```
select order_id,
count (case when stage = 'stage_1' then 1 else null end) as stage_1,
count (case when stage = 'stage_2' then 1 else null end) as stage_2,
count (case when stage = 'stage_3' then 1 else null end) as stage_3,
count (case when stage = 'stage_4' then 1 else null end) as stage_4

from table

group by order_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL implementation doesn't provide `PIVOT` query, your approach is a common workaround for PIVOT-ing.

But in some other SQL implementation like BigQuery, you can query like below and get same result.  Kindly check if your SQL supports `PIVOT` first.

```sql
DECLARE sample ARRAY<STRUCT<order_id INT64, stage INT64>> DEFAULT [
  (111, 1), (111, 1), (222, 1), (111, 2), (111, 3), (111, 4), (222, 2)
];

WITH dataset AS (
 SELECT * FROM UNNEST(sample)
)
SELECT * FROM dataset PIVOT( COUNT(stage) AS stage FOR stage IN (1, 2, 3, 4) );

output:
+----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| order_id | stage_1 | stage_2 | stage_3 | stage_4 |
+----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|      111 |       2 |       1 |       1 |       1 |
|      222 |       1 |       1 |       0 |       0 |
+----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```